# Using a GridView in asp.net but am using a submit button outside the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am using a `GridView` to display error information to be verified by the user. Then the user is given fillable fields (`datepicker`, `dropdownlist`, `textbox`) to fix the errors. These are outside of the `GridView`.

After, they have a submit button to save the changes to a sql log. The problem I am having is that because I'm passing in `object sender, GridViewRowEventsArg e`, the button doesn't recognize the `GridView` and I get an error:

```
No overload for 'btnSaveMemberErrorEdit_ButtonClicked' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

I am using `asp.net` with c# code behind. Sample code is:

ASP:

```
    <div id="actionItemAccordion">
<h3>Action Items</h3>
<asp:Panel runat="server">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridActionItems" DataKeyNames="ErrorKey"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Action Items Were Found." ShowHeader="true"
        ClientIDMode="Static" Width="100%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Action Item" DataField="ActionItem" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Month" DataField="Month" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data" DataField="DCode" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data2" DataField="D2Code" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbWinner" AutoPostBack="true" Font-Size="Smaller" >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="D1 Correct" Enabled="true" Value="D1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="D2 Correct" Enabled="true" Value="D2" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" Width="850px"></asp:Label>
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Edit Any Necessary Changes" Style="text-align: center"
            Font-Size="Medium" Visible="true" Font-Bold="true" Width="100%" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Effective Date: " Style="text-align: right"
            Font-Size="Small" Visible="true" Width="200px" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEffectiveDate" Text="" Style="text-align: left"
            ClientIDMode="Static" Font-Size="13px" Columns="15" Height="15" Width="15%" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Termination Date: " Style="text-align: right"
            Font-Size="Small" Visible="true" Width="200px" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTerminationDate" Text="" Style="text-align: left"
            ClientIDMode="Static" Font-Size="13px" Columns="15" Height="15" Width="15%" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="New/Corrected Name: " Style="text-align: right"
            Font-Size="Small" Visible="true" Width="200px" />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlNewCode" AutoPostBack="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            Style="text-align: left" Width="220" BackColor="AliceBlue" ClientIDMode="Static"
            DataTextField="Code" DataValueField="CodeKey">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" Width="850px"></asp:Label>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Notes: " Style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle"
            Font-Size="Small" Visible="true" Width="200px" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNotes" Text="" Style="text-align: left" ClientIDMode="Static"
            Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Font-Size="10px" Columns="100" Height="100"
            Width="50%" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveErrorEdit" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="btnSaveErrorEdit_ButtonClicked"
            Height="30px" Enabled="true" Width="95px" Style="margin-left: 330px; margin-top: 70px;
            margin-bottom: 25px; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px;" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancelEdit" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="return CancelEdit();"
            Enabled="true" Height="30px" Width="70px" Style="margin-right: 330px; margin-top: 70px;
            margin-bottom: 25px; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px;" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void btnSaveErrorEdit_ButtonClicked(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int hiddenErrorKey = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);

        this.assignCorrect = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;           

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("some_storedProc");
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add("@ErrorKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = hiddenErrorKey;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EffectiveDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.txtEffectiveDate;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TerminationDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.txtTerminationDate;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Notes", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = this.txtNotes;
        command.Parameters.Add("@NameOfInputUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = this.lblInputUserName;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = this.assignWinner;
        Utilities.Exec_Qry(this.Application["some_connection"].ToString(), command);   
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? which row do you want to use? can you elaborate a little on your program flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the function to take arguments for the asp:button

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Then you can grab the GridView in the behind code using

```
var button = sender as Button;
var view = button.FindControl("gridActionItems") as GridView;
```

Then you can access the elements as needed.

Comment: Heh, I was tired last night. Thinking on that you can just grab it directly since it's not in a bound control. As for your other comment, there is a good point, I was assuming he knew exactly what rows of the GridView he wants to use.

Comment: The user will fill in the fields, which are not in the gridview, and then in the gridview they will choose a radio button for the winner. When the submit button is clicked, they should get the information from the gridview for the row that the radio button is selected and the information that they filled in. I thought I could call it directly, but it gives me the above error. So, would I need to do as you stated in the code above, or is there something else you were thinking. I guess I misunderstood your answers.

Comment: protected void btnSaveErrorEdit_ButtonClicked(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) needs to become protected void btnSaveErrorEdit_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) to handle the button click. From there, you can loop through the GridView in the behind code and check for which radio button(s) is selected and build your SQL query based on that row.

Comment: @user3579710 hey if this was the answer to your issue mark this as the accepted answer plox